# Console app not triggering ItemUpdated event Sharepoint 2010

Tags: c#, events, sharepoint, triggers, sharepoint-2010

I have developed a regular console app in C# that is connecting to a list on a SharePoint 2010 site, and updates two fields with new values. The list has an event receiver and when an item is updated it should trigger ItemUpdated event. And it does when I manually updates the fields through SP UI. But it does not trigger the event when item is updated via my console app? Why is that?

```
item["someField"] = value;    
item.Update();
```

What do I need to do so it will trigger the event when the item is updated with new values?

Comment: Can you provide the code for your console application?
Also wrap your ItemUpdated event with a try catch block and the log the exception to see if there are any error message [My Event Receiver Doesn’t Fire](https://pholpar.wordpress.com/2010/02/15/my-event-receiver-doesnt-fire/)

Comment: Is the console app running as a particular user, or as a system account?